# Having fill issues with shapes in p5.js when using bezier() and curve() functions

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm having issues figuring out how to fill concave shapes when using the bezier() or curve() functions in the p5.js library. Not sure if there's another function I can use to get the same result without fill issues or what exactly I'm doing wrong here. I attached a picture of what the output looks like in the full program, along with snippets of the two objects I'm having issues with.

I've tried adding a fourth side to close the shape that way, but it doesn't seem to fix anything and from what I understand isn't necessary when CLOSE is passed to endShape()

[Picture of Full Output (at time of posting)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxGeM.png)

[Full Code (Note: code has been modified and a temporary fix has been implemented since posting the question)](https://github.com/bthreewitt-spam/uol_cm1005/blob/master/topic2/lesson1/hack_it_robot_2/robotParade.js)

**Arm**

```js
function setup()
{
    createCanvas(200, 350); //modified for snippet
}

function draw() {
    let x = -270;//added for snippet
    let y = -450;//added for snippet
    let r,g,b = 200;//added for snippet
    
    
    strokeWeight(6);
    fill(r-40,g-40,b-40);

    beginShape(); // FIXME: Fix fill issue
    curve(x-150, y+490,x+340, y+470,x+420, y+775,x+420, y+680);
    bezier(x+337, y+520,x+370, y+550,x+370, y+680,x+380, y+775);
    bezier(x+380, y+775,x+370, y+680,x+370, y+550,x+337, y+520);
    bezier(x+380, y+775,x+390, y+780,x+410, y+780,x+420, y+775);
    endShape(CLOSE);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/processing/p5.js/releases/download/v1.4.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```

**Hand Cup**

```js
function setup()
{
    createCanvas(150, 80); // modified for snippet
}

function draw() {
     let x = -300;  // Added for snippet
     let y = -750; // Added for snippet
     let r,g,b = 200; // added for snippet
    
    
    strokeWeight(6);
    fill(r-40,g-40,b-40);


    strokeWeight(6);
    beginShape(); // FIXME: Fix fill issue
    bezier(x+420, y+775,x+430, y+790,x+430, y+780,x+440, y+820);
    bezier(x+380, y+775,x+370, y+790,x+370, y+780,x+360, y+820);
    bezier(x+440, y+820,x+410, y+830,x+390, y+830,x+360, y+820);
    endShape(CLOSE);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/processing/p5.js/releases/download/v1.4.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```